# ReactJS: TypeError: Failed to Fetch (Not CORS related)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch

I am trying to a simple get request using the Fetch library in React.

I have the following code (shortened for brevity)

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
     this.state = {
       username: "",
       password: "",
       stories: [],
       isLoggedIn: false
      };
    }

   getAllStories = async () => {
      let res = await fetch(storiesAPI, {header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')})
     let json = await res.json()
     await this.setState({stories: json})
     console.log(this.state.stories) 
    }

componentDidMount (){
   if (localStorage.token) {
    this.setState({
    isLoggedIn: true
  });
  } else {
    this.setState({
    isLoggedIn: false
  });
  }
  this.getAllStories();
 }

 render() {
  return (
    <div>
       <h1>Hi</h1>
    </div>
    )
  }

  export default App;
```

As soon as the component mounts I get a failed to fetch error, which I initially thought was because of a CORS error,

[image: picture of error]

because currently my `server.js` file looks like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const parser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const passport = require('./config/passport')()


const app = express()
  var corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy 
  browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
  };

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000)
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(parser.json())
app.use(passport.initialize())


app.use(require('./routes/index'))

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
 console.log('Server listening on port ' + 
app.get('port'))
})
```

I thought that I was doing everything right, but the following is what I've tried:

1.fetch headers from `let res = await fetch(storiesAPI, {header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')})` to let res = await fetch(storiesAPI, { credentials: "same-origin" })

2. Removing the CORS option

3.Adding a proxyurl in reference to a stack overflow post

Comment: You fetch statement is wrong, change it to fetch(storiesAPI, {mode: 'cors', headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}})

Comment: I see. Your recommendation worked, but may I ask, can you clarify times when using `mode: 'cors'` is unnecessary when making a fetch request? This is the first time I've had to specify it.

Comment: I could see that you are specifying CORS in your service code, hence you instruct the client to use CORS mode.

Comment: CORS headers belong on the **response** not the request. You can't grant yourself permission to read someone else's data.

Comment: There is a little arrow next to the "failed to fetch" Error. Click it to get more details about the error.

Comment: @Quentin, is this in reference to my comment or Ben's? Is solution his solution wrong then? I noticed that when I when I used his the fetch now only works sometimes, mainly upon refresh, but not when switching routes in react.

Comment: @Lullaby — Your code and Ben's comment.

Comment: I see, then the issue remains unresolved.

Comment: Ah my bad, I was too quick to post. Deleting the answer!

Comment: However the fetch statement is incorrectly written. {header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')}) is invalid.